# $_POST variable is empty after form input

Tags: php, forms, post

I'm trying to develop a simple login system in php and after following some newbies tutorials I came out with this solution:

A simple form in html:

```
<form class = "form-horizontal" action = "{$BASE_URL}controllers/users/login.php" method = "POST">
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <label for = "username" class = "col-sm-3 control-label">Username</label>
                            <div class = "col-sm-8">
                                <input type = "text" name = "username" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Username" required = "" autofocus = "" autocomplete = "off">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <label for = "password" class = "col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div class = "col-sm-8">
                                <input type = "password" name = "password" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Password" required = "" autocomplete = "off">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <div class = "col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-3">
                                <input type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary" value = "Log In"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class = "col-sm-5 text-right">
                                <a href = "" class = "small" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#forgotPassword"> Forgot Password?</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

where **{$BASE_URL}** is

```
$BASE_DIR = '/home/luiscosta/PhpstormProjects/LBAW-FEUP/';
```

and then after submiting my login info I print the $_POST variable on my **login.php**

```
<?php

var_dump($_POST);
```

result:

```
array(0) { }
```

I don't think the solution to change the max_input_values would be doing any difference since the form is really small and the defaut value(1000) is acceptable.

I have also a config.php file where I include the Smarty library which I dont think has any to do with my problem.

```
 <?php



include_once($BASE_DIR . 'lib/helpers/functions.php');
include_once($BASE_DIR . 'lib/helpers/Html.class.php');

include_once($BASE_DIR . 'lib/permissions/PagePermissions.class.php');
include_once($BASE_DIR . 'lib/permissions/Permission.class.php');
include_once($BASE_DIR . 'lib/permissions/AuthUser.class.php');
include_once($BASE_DIR . 'lib/permissions/GuestUser.class.php');
include_once($BASE_DIR . 'lib/permissions/AdminUser.class.php');
include_once($BASE_DIR . 'lib/permissions/ModUser.class.php');
include_once($BASE_DIR . 'lib/permissions/PagePermissions.class.php');
include_once($BASE_DIR . 'lib/permissions/ResourcePermission.class.php');

include_once ($BASE_DIR . '/lib/smarty/Smarty.class.php');


$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->template_dir = '../templates';
$smarty->compile_dir = '../templates_c';
$smarty->assign('BASE_URL', $BASE_URL);


$_SESSION['logged_in'] = isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) ? $_SESSION['logged_in'] : false;
$smarty->assign('LOGGED_IN', $_SESSION['logged_in']);
```

I don't know why the POST variable is being wiped. This looks pretty straight forward with the **action call** passing the form "names" in the $POST array. 
Does anyone have a clue in what's going on?

Regards

Comment: your html form sends posts to my login.php page just fine.

Comment: Could you double confirm the exact post url? You imply it to be: `/home/luiscosta/PhpstormProjects/LBAW-FEUP/controllers/users/login.php` which possibly is not a url?

Comment: Do all those includes happen on your login.php page before you `var_dump($_POST)`? The form looks fine, so I'd assume it's something in one of those.

Comment: between `<?php` and  `include_once($BASE_DIR.'lib/helpers/functions.php');`, please add `print_r($_POST); die();` and see if it prints the post variables correctly. Then do the same thing but drop it down further and further between the includes, so you can tell if one of the included files has cleared `$_POST`

Comment: between <?php and include_once($BASE_DIR.'lib/helpers/functions.php'); it prints an empty array, like the print on my login.php @Gravy

Comment: I don't understand. If my var_dump is printing somehing I can assume login.php is being reached, right? Why and where is my _POST going through to get wiped?

Comment: From command line `curl --data "test=hello&test2=world" http://replace.with.url.from.form.action.here` - see if your print_r catches the test & test2

Comment: I did this as you suggested:
`curl --data "test=hello&test2=world" http://localhost:63342/LBAW-FEUP/controllers/users/login.php`
and I got this: `<!doctype html><title>404 Not Found</title><h1 style="text-align: center">404 Not Found</h1><hr/><p style="text-align: center">PhpStorm 2016.3.3</p>`